# why is question still on hold

Tags: discussion

[reducing ambiguity in the construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216288/reducing-ambiguity-in-the-construction)

The details were included in an edit as requested. Why is it on hold?

Comment: As the very first comment under the linked question points out, the text being queried mentions *X's strength and **Y's** belief*. Most comments (including those from OP) imply it should have been *X's strength and [**X's**] belief*, but no edit has been made to reflect this anomaly/error/ambiguity (which was and remains the reason for my "Unclear" closevote).

Answer (score 4):

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

> Users with 3,000 reputation can cast up to 24 reopen votes per day.
>   **When a question reaches 5 reopen votes, it is no longer closed,** and
>   new answers may be submitted. You may only vote to close or reopen a
>   question once. To cast a reopen vote, click the "reopen" link beneath
>   the question.

As of today your question has received one reopen vote and one delete vote. Your question needs four more reopen votes.

Comment: For those who are down voting my question routinely without any explanation, at least include a solid reason which you should have when doing so. Someone read this post and went ahead further downvoting my question one more time making it -5. It's not an unreasonable question. Once whatever was lacking in the question is fixed (say through an edit) then vote for reopen. For those who can't see the reason behind the question or use of the question, why screw the ones who see or have use for it.

Comment: @JoeBlack; Your edit has certainly not removed all the problems; anybody who thinks "Can [a phrase] be seen singularly?"  is unclear or not useful not only can but should downvote.  The responsibility for minimising downvotes rests with the questioner, not the downvoter.

Comment: This is a ridiculous sentiment especially in trying to defend an unnecessary case of downvoting. You didn't quote the full sentence where it provides an example underneath that clarifies it. Further, the discussion below the question explains it further. Talking about responsibility seems vacuous when there are folks who just went on with the herd mentality and downvoted without even paying attention. the views has remained the same at 37 because there is no way to bump up the question and the mods won't reopen. If I file another question, you'd tag it duplicate and then pass blame. Wow.

Comment: Mods, any recourse here?

Comment: Each moderator acts on his own motion, but I have no wish to open a question which the community has closed and which seems to have a perfectly reasonable answer already. Others may feel that another answer is needed, and they can vote to re-open. That includes other moderators. What I *have* done is edited out the name-calling in your comment. You may not like the way the community works: that's fine. But in order to change it, you need to work with it and not to vilify it.